# write square root of expression in text file in

Tags: ascii-art

i need to write root of an expression in text file, but all of the expression have to be below that root. Some tips ? is there any way to use symbols from MS word , and write that in docx file? or something similarly

Comment: write the latex-code for the expression. e.g. `\sqrt{3*x_1+2*y_1}`

Comment: ...or have a look @ http://asciitex.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

```
 __________
√  2x + 3y
```

Or other ASCII art.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but i have to generate root of very large expressions with multi line fraction. Something like this [link](http://www.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/products/precip/CWlink/MJO/CLIVAR/cor-1.PNG)

Comment: Surely you can think of ways to combine characters to make a reasonable faximile of that.